# Determine whether $[(p \vee q \vee r) \wedge (\neg p \to s) \wedge (\neg q \to s)] \to (r \to s)$ is a tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Determine whether $[(p \vee q \vee r) \wedge (\neg p \to s) \wedge (\neg q \to s)] \to (r \to s)$ is a tautology.

I am having trouble proving this formally and will appreciate all the help.

Comment: Consider $16$ cases.

Comment: $p\to q$ is equivalent to ~$p$ v $q$

Comment: Please use mathjax, as on mobile devices, all the symbols are only boxes.

Comment: Assume not, i.e. the antecedent is T and the consequent is F. This second assumption means: $v(r)= \text T$ and $v(s)= \text F$. Now, see what happens to the antecedent.

Answer (score 5):

That is not a tautology, as you can easily see by constructing the appropriate truth table, or vey the following reasoning.

Suppose $p, q, r$ are true and $s$ is false.

Then $p \vee q \vee r$ is true, $\neg p \to s$ is true and $\neg q \to s$ is true. Note also that $r \to s$ is false.

Hence you have a combination of truth values for the component statements that make the whole statement false.

Therefore, the compound statement $[(p \vee q \vee r) \wedge (\neg p \to s) \wedge (\neg q \to s)] \to (r \to s)$ is not a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $4$ cases for $r$ and $s$:
$$
r = T, s = T
$$
$$
r = T, s = F
$$
$$
r = F, s = T
$$
$$
r = F, s = F
$$
You can prove/disprove each case by applying the standard laws (De Morgan's, etc) on $p$ and $q$.